Tidy up datasets - converting subheaders into column
I received a txt data file that looks like this:
# test A response c
1   x1     1
2   x2     0
..       ..
324 x324   5
# test P response 8
1   x1     2
2   x2     1
..       ..
501 x501   4
# test 7 response t
1   x1     2
2   x2     1
..       ..
936 x936   4

It has two long columns separated by tab many subheaders (e.g. "test A response c"). Notice under each subheader, the number of rows is variable. The total number of rows is about 10,000. I want to tidy it up and drop all the subheaders, to as following:
x      y Test   Response  
x1     1 test A response c
x2     0 test A response c
..       ..
x324   5 test A response c
x1     2 test P response 8
x2     1 test P response 8
..       ..
x501   4 test P response 8
x1     2 test 7 response t
x2     1 test 7 response t
..       ..
x936   4 test 7 response t

What's the best way to do this?

One way to solve your problem
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(Test = replace(x, !grepl("test", x), NA),
         Response = replace(y, !grepl("response", y), NA)) |> 
  fill(Test, Response) |> 
  filter(!grepl("test", x))

     x y   Test   Response
1   x1 1 test A response c
2   x2 0 test A response c
3 x324 5 test A response c
4   x1 2 test P response 8
5   x2 1 test P response 8
6 x501 4 test P response 8
7   x1 2 test 7 response t
8   x2 1 test 7 response t
9 x936 4 test 7 response t

data
# read file
df = read.delim("file.txt", header=FALSE, , col.names=c("x", "y"))
# toy example:
df = read.delim(text="test A    response c
x1  1
x2  0
x324    5
test P  response 8
x1  2
x2  1
x501    4
test 7  response t
x1  2
x2  1
x936    4", header=FALSE, , col.names=c("x", "y"))

df
        x          y
1  test A response c
2      x1          1
3      x2          0
4    x324          5
5  test P response 8
6      x1          2
7      x2          1
8    x501          4
9  test 7 response t
10     x1          2
11     x2          1
12   x936          4


Aren't you forgetting that the test rows start with the comment char "#"?

Elegante! It works. BTW, I was toying with the idea to use fill(data, ..., .direction = c("down")). You showed the way. Thanks

Base R solution (no packages).  Define a function which takes a subset of lines and converts them to a data frame by splitting the first line, reading in the rest and then appending the information parsed out from the first line.  Finally rbind the data frames together.  The row names identify which group and line number within group that row is from.  The data is generated reproducibly in the Note at the end which should be run first.
Lines2DF <- function(x) {
   s <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], " +"))
   data.frame(
      read.table(textConnection(x), col.names = c("", "x", "y"))[-1], 
      Test = paste(s[2], s[3]),
      Response = paste(s[4], s[5])
   )
}

L <- readLines("tcollar.dat")
do.call("rbind", by(L, cumsum(grepl("test", L)), Lines2DF))

giving
       x y   Test   Response
1.1   x1 1 test A response c
1.2   x2 0 test A response c
1.3 x324 5 test A response c
2.1   x1 2 test P response 8
2.2   x2 1 test P response 8
2.3 x501 4 test P response 8
3.1   x1 2 test 7 response t
3.2   x2 1 test 7 response t
3.3 x936 4 test 7 response t

Note
Input shown reproducibly
Lines <- "# test A response c
1   x1     1
2   x2     0
324 x324   5
# test P response 8
1   x1     2
2   x2     1
501 x501   4
# test 7 response t
1   x1     2
2   x2     1
936 x936   4
"
cat(Lines, file = "tcollar.dat")


A bit more verbose Tidyverse approach.
Read lines to a vector, detect sections from rows starting with "#", split by sections and parse each split. Section headers are used as list names, after binding all rows those end up in a column named "header" which gets separated into "Test" and "Response" with separate_wider_regex().
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

txt <- "# test A response c
1   x1     1
2   x2     0
324 x324   5
# test P response 8
1   x1     2
2   x2     1
501 x501   4
# test 7 response t
1   x1     2
2   x2     1
936 x936   4"

# replace `txt` with txt file name
txt_lines <- read_lines(txt)
(sections <- str_detect(txt_lines, "^#") |> cumsum())
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

  # split by sections
split(txt_lines, sections) |> 
  # first rows from each split to list names
  (\(x) set_names(x, map_chr(x, 1)))() |> 
  # parse each split, get only x & y columns and skip header line
  map(read_table, col_types = "_ci", col_names = c("x", "y"), skip = 1) |> 
  # combine list of frames to a single frame
  list_rbind(names_to = "header") |> 
  # only named patterns are used to fill columns
  separate_wider_regex(header, patterns = c("^#\\s*", Test = ".*(?= response)", "\\s*", Response = ".*"))

Result:
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   Test   Response   x         y
#>   <chr>  <chr>      <chr> <int>
#> 1 test A response c x1        1
#> 2 test A response c x2        0
#> 3 test A response c x324      5
#> 4 test P response 8 x1        2
#> 5 test P response 8 x2        1
#> 6 test P response 8 x501      4
#> 7 test 7 response t x1        2
#> 8 test 7 response t x2        1
#> 9 test 7 response t x936      4

Created on 2024-09-21 with reprex v2.1.1
